# Format of private key

Tags: private-key, wallet-import-format

On [this website](http://directory.io/), we can see that the the private key 1 is written in this format.

> 5HpHagT65TZzG1PH3CSu63k8DbpvD8s5ip4nEB3kEsreAnchuDf

I would like to know what is this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Base58 Wallet Import format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Base58_Wallet_Import_format).

It is composed of the alphanumeric characters excluding `0OIl` (zero, capital O, capital I, and lowercase L). The format includes an error checking code which makes it highly unlikely to mistype a key.

The format is also in use for addresses. Private keys start with a five. Pay-to-pubkey-hash addresses start with a one, pay-to-script-hash addresses start with a three.